# Full width class - foundation framework

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

first time user of Foundation framework, I've developed all my previous websites with Bootstrap but now I'm forced to built one website with foundation. I noticed they are pretty similar but somehow different frameworks.

I've encountered a problem and hope you can help me with this.

I need to add a banner to a website which is full width and text which is within the grid and has a bg which is also full width, see what I mean here:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="fullWidth">
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.svg"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="bg-tagline">
                <h1 class="tagline">some text here</h1>             
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css:

```css
.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: initial;
}
.banner {
  background: white url("images/baner.jpg") no-repeat center;
  height: 590px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1%;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
}
.bg-tagline {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.bg-tagline h1 {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no a *"full width"* class in foundation framework; Normally, in those layout types, I'd just use the elements off the framework, for instance:

```
<header id="banner">
    <div class="slogan">Your text banner here</div>
</div>
```

And of course some CSS like you have already. If you need something elaborated (like a layout using foundation's classes), I'd put inside `div.slogan` a `div.row`, and start building layout from there, of course that *row* would be restricted to the max width from the framework.

BTW, if you need to have the entire framework having a wider width for the rows, you can change the framework settings and re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to make utility class for rows:

```
.row.fullwidth {
    max-width:100em; // set your override width here
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That way whenever I need a full width section I just do:

```
  <div class="row fullwidth">
    <!--- content --->
  </div>
```